# Is it possible for any set to be an element of itself?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible for any set to be an element of itself? I want brief explanation for whether it's possible or not.

Comment: No. That's an answer!

Answer (score 0):

In ZF, the answer is **no**. The reason is  [Axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) is one of the axioms there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the axioms.

In $\mathsf {ZF}$, as said before, this is not possible.

According to other axiomatizations, like [Quine's New Foundations](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine-nf/), we can have the [universal set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_set#Theories_of_universality) $V$, and thus:

> $V \in V$.